# Shift key stuck in software after login, reboot fixes this

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, macos, sleep-wake

I have a very wierd issue with my macbook air early2015. The shift key is almost always stuck after I wake the computer and login. However this does not affect text for some reason, I can still use the shift key normally in all text fields. It does however affect the slow animation and multiple selection stuff that happens while pressing shift, which makes using the mac almost impossible.

This is always fixed after I reboot, but 9/10 times the key is stuck again after I wake it up and login. Additionally, the problem only happens if the laptop was sleeping long enough for the login screen to appear. The key works fine on the hardware side so I'm pretty sure its a Software thing.

I also couldn't find anyone else with this problem.

Comment: Similar issue but my problem goes away after a reboot and comes back only after I put the computer to sleep.

Comment: Try resetting the SMC https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295

Comment: Using Karabiner Event Viewer, I saw "flags:shift" only for mouse events (trackpad or external, I have both).  I also wonder if it is related to Karabiner-Elements, anyone else using that?

Answer (score 1):

I have a workaround which works and involves going to the login screen. Sometimes that is enough to fix. If that doesn't work, switch to the guest user and then log out. That always does it for me.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is](https://www.jamf.com/jamf-nation/discussions/19020/mouse-keyboard-issues-after-sleep-and-wake-up) another discussion on this issue (but there's no universal solution offered at the moment).

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Answers which are barely more than a link may be deleted, because they're not useful when the link breaks. Please include a summary.